# Does Symfony2 Have Filter Input Built in Classes

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning symfony2 and curious about how to filter user input in symfony2. In zend framework 2 they provide standard filter classes to filter input easily such as (Alnum, Digit, Alpha, HtmlEntities) so how about symfony ? I have been searching it but no luck I only found standard validation in symfony2.

Example for filtering inn zf2:

```
$filter = new \Zend\I18n\Filter\Alnum();
echo $filter->filter("This is (my) content: 123");
// Returns "Thisismycontent123"
```

If symfony doesn't provide standard filter classes is there any bundle out there to do the same thing?

Comment: Symfony does have functionality which allows for input validation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html. Is this what you mean ?

Comment: @Moshikaro No, I mean filtering that used for removing unwanted portions of input, not validation.

Comment: I just put an example filtering in zf2, hope this help you to understand my question :)

Comment: DataTransformer? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: Sorry, I know of one bundle who tries to solve this: https://github.com/rdohms/dms-filter-bundle

Comment: @BennoZeeman it seems DataTransformers needs we create our own filter, since it's common thing I prever to find "ready to use" classes :)

Comment: @Moshikaro Thanks :) I will try it. but if there anyone else who want to suggest other bundles are very welcome.